# Computing the Covariance Matrix of a Huge Data in Spark (Python)Google Cloud?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I have 10M sample of 1000 factors. Each factor is stored in a separate file. Therefore there are 1000 files each includes 1M double. If A is the data matrix with d = 1000 rows and n=1M columns,

I need to compute C = A*transpose(A), which is a d * d matrix.

I don’t know an efficient way using pySpark and google cloud(the data is stored there) to compute C.

Comment: This problem is probably not related to GCP itself, but I recommend you to try GPUs to do your matrix computation. in GCP you can add GPUs to you cluster at cluster creation time.